# Change cursor symbol to hand when image/button focused in mac

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing desktop application in mac using Xamarin forms, in that when I focused on Image/Button I need to change cursor symbol to hand symbol.
I googled it but I don't found any solution to solve this.
Could you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding Triggers to style as follows:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: i am using Xamarin forms for developing desktop application in macOs not Wpf. In Xamarin forms there is no Mouseover property

Answer (score 0):

Just override `ResetCursorRects` method inside `ButtonRenderer` .

#### Update

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Button),typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace ColeForms.macOS
{

    public class MyRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {

        public override void ResetCursorRects()
        {
            base.ResetCursorRects();
            //change cursor style to hand shape while hovering on the view
            AddCursorRect(Bounds, NSCursor.PointingHandCursor); 
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: it's working but it overrides the button styles and events but I don't want it for that I need to remove the line SetNativeControl(button); but without it hover effects are not effecting. how can I solve this.

Comment: Ok , you can just override `ResetCursorRects` method inside renderer , check my update .

Comment: currently mac is not available. I will check and update to you once problem is solved

Comment: Ok , no problem .